# Storage size on disk can achieve a 20% reduction from the compressed size

Tags: powerbi

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-dataset-modes-understand

It reads: "When refreshed, data is compressed and optimized and then stored to disk by the VertiPaq storage engine. When loaded from disk into memory, it's possible to see 10x compression. So, it's reasonable to expect that 10 GB of source data can compress to about 1 GB in size. Storage size on disk can achieve a 20% reduction from the compressed size."

1. So source data is compressed when storing to disk. How much is the compression?
2. When data is loaded from disk to memory then there is 10x compression.
3. What does the following mean: Storage size on disk can achieve a 20% reduction from the compressed size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your source is a 10 GB uncompressed text format like a CSV file.

When you load that file into Power BI, the VertiPaq engine compresses that data in a format that is particularly efficient if most of the columns don't have nearly as many distinct values as there are rows (low cardinality). More detail on compression [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/inside-vertipaq-in-power-bi-compress-for-success-68b888d9d463) or [here](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2449192&seqNum=3). After this compression, the model might only need 1 GB of working memory since it's in a more efficient format. Check out [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-reduce-your-power-bi-model-size-by-90-b2f834c9f12e) for tips on reducing the file size.

When you go to save the PBIX file to disk, there's a bit more compression since some of the space needed in memory to keep things running fast doesn't need to be explicitly stored to disk, so the saved PBIX might only be 800 MB on your hard drive even though the task manager shows it consuming 1 GB of RAM.